# How can I preserve \n characters in my jelastic environment variable?

Tags: jelastic

I am trying to install the following Jelastic manifest:

```yaml
type: update
name: Not working

onInstall:
  - getPublicKey
  - forEach(nodes.cp):
    - api:
      - method: environment.control.SetContainerEnvVars
        params:
          nodeId: ${@i.id}
          vars:
            SOME_SECRET: '{"type": "RS256", "key": "${response.out}"}'
actions:
  getPublicKey:
    - cmd [cp]: |
        curl -s -H "Authorization: my-token" http://${nodes.auth.master.intIP}:9011/api/key | jq -r '.keys[] | select(.algorithm | contains("RS256")).publicKey'
```

The response output in the Jelastic console for the `getPublicKey` action reads:

```
cmd [cp: 113094].response: {"result":0,"errOut":"","nodeid":113094,"exitStatus":0,"out":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAprg9fCTMSfm6psfOnhfL\nUDdlrV39LU9p8msWsYUjO4M2E6m5GcADYPHkLdLV/c7W+vgDvpHLfxU8peP/21BS\nCVQVYEFpYCRY2NcOTsP2zLj7PTAFiw8wyOwK7u05EM7CgK7LS6rDotMIZFNzIPG5\nfJNz+hDyhvvNhWg56dcmPIrBxN26Piv+N6vtWqJDuVQNXKwEk/w4uUxiz9gNSEi/\nhJlLgHxTsSMh9YXUIyKn8QBACF4GQKmToBPW7ScEnX/Bm6y9g4JbYYIwWBTRwUfy\nkhbojk6mAPcKY+diWM2PE385pyjIWshKUgtBKcgPNJXDU3RPXAdzN0hQ1sJbNV5z\nzwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"}
```

Here we can clearly see the newlines displayed as `\n` characters. For some reason, the newline characters `\n` are interpreted as true newlines in the environment variable `SOME_SECRET`, which now reads incorrectly (this is the result of the `env` command):

```sh
SOME_SECRET={"type": "RS256", "key": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The variable value is displayed until the first newline character, which is not what I want.

How can I make sure the `\n` get outputted to the `SOME_SECRET` environment variable and that they are not replaced with a real new line? When I execute the `env` command on my ubuntu image, I want to see this:

```sh
SOME_SECRET={"type": "RS256", "key": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAprg9fCTMSfm6psfOnhfL\nUDdlrV39LU9p8msWsYUjO4M2E6m5GcADYPHkLdLV/c7W+vgDvpHLfxU8peP/21BS\nCVQVYEFpYCRY2NcOTsP2zLj7PTAFiw8wyOwK7u05EM7CgK7LS6rDotMIZFNzIPG5\nfJNz+hDyhvvNhWg56dcmPIrBxN26Piv+N6vtWqJDuVQNXKwEk/w4uUxiz9gNSEi/\nhJlLgHxTsSMh9YXUIyKn8QBACF4GQKmToBPW7ScEnX/Bm6y9g4JbYYIwWBTRwUfy\nkhbojk6mAPcKY+diWM2PE385pyjIWshKUgtBKcgPNJXDU3RPXAdzN0hQ1sJbNV5z\nzwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following manifest does exactly what I want:

```yaml
type: update
name: Working

onInstall:
  - getPublicKey
  - api:
    - method: environment.control.AddContainerEnvVars
      params:
        nodeGroup: cp
        vars:
          SOME_SECRET: '{"type": "RS256", "key": "${response.out}"}'
actions:
  getPublicKey:
    - cmd [cp]: |
        curl -s -H "Authorization: some-key" http://${nodes.auth.master.intIP}:9011/api/key | jq -r '.keys[] | select(.algorithm | contains("RS256")).publicKey' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'
```

Note the use of `sed` in the `getPublicKey` to format the response output appropriately. Also, note the use of `environment.control.AddContainerEnvVars` instead of `environment.control.SetContainerEnvVars`. The latter removes all environment variables on the node group (except `PATH`), while the former really adds new environment variables (and overwrites existing ones with the new values).

Finally, note that it is necessary to have the `getPublicKey` action. The following manifest would not work (I don't know why):

```yaml
type: update
name: Not Working

onInstall:
  - cmd [cp]: |
      curl -s -H "Authorization: some-key" http://${nodes.auth.master.intIP}:9011/api/key | jq -r '.keys[] | select(.algorithm | contains("RS256")).publicKey' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'
  - api:
    - method: environment.control.AddContainerEnvVars
      params:
        nodeGroup: cp
        vars:
          SOME_SECRET: '{"type": "RS256", "key": "${response.out}"}'
```